# How can I count the numbers in a string of mixed text/numbers

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-3.5, string, count

So what I'm trying to do, is take a job number, which looks like this xxx123432, and count the digits in the entry, but not the letters.  I want to then assign the number of numbers to a variable, and use that variable to provide a check against the job numbers to determine if they are in a valid format.

I've already figured out how to perform the check, but I have no clue how to go about counting the numbers in the job number.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Do you need to calculate `1+2+3+4+3+2`? Or count a number of numbers (6)? Or what?

Comment: I need to count the number of numbers.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using LINQ :

```
var count = jobId.Count(x => Char.IsDigit(x));
```

or

```
var count = jobId.Count(Char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: @mathieu- Besides syntax, whats the real difference between these two?

Comment: @MAW74656 : no behavioral differences. first ones uses a declared predicate (ie a function that takes 1 arg of type char and returns bool) and second uses directly the function

Answer (score 4):

```
int x = "xxx123432".Count(c => Char.IsNumber(c)); // 6
```

or

```
int x = "xxx123432".Count(c => Char.IsDigit(c)); // 6
```

The difference between these two methods see at [Char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Char.IsNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?

```
string jobId = "xxx123432";
int digitsCount = 0;
foreach(char c in jobId)
{
  if(Char.IsDigit(c))
    digitsCount++;
}
```

And you could use LINQ, like this:

```
string jobId = "xxx123432";
int digitsCount = jobId.Count(c => char.IsDigit(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string str = "t12X234";
    var reversed = str.Reverse().ToArray();
    int digits = 0;

    while (digits < str.Length &&
           Char.IsDigit(reversed[digits])) digits++;

    int num = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(str.Length - digits));
```

This gives num 234 as output if that is what you need.

The other linq/lambda variants just count characters which I think is not completely correct if you have a string like "B2B_MESSAGE_12344", because it would count the 2 in B2B.

But I'm not sure if I understood correctly what number of numbers means. Is it the count of numbers (other answers) or the number that numbers form (this answer).

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear on that.  I was looking for the count of numbers, but thanks for your answer anyway.