# A c# project! should i use String arrays? (is that even a thing?!)

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program in c# where I'm supposed to tell the user to insert random characters and then divide those random characters into letters and numbers and count how many i have of each.

anyone has any idea how to do so?
thanks!
ps: i'm new to c# and programming alltogether :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want help with your homework, please [edit] your question to show what you've come up with so far, and explain why it isn't working the way you expected it to. See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting Number of Letters in a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096494/counting-number-of-letters-in-a-string-variable)

Comment: And [How can I count the numbers in a string of mixed text/numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983748/how-can-i-count-the-numbers-in-a-string-of-mixed-text-numbers/5983831)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`char.IsDigit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=net-5.0) or [`char.IsNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=net-5.0) to check if it's a "number"(digit):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int digitCount = input.Count(char.IsDigit);
int letterCount = input.Length - digitCount;
```

You need to add `using System.Linq` to be able to use `Enumerable.Count`.

---

Since you now have asked for counting vowels. Vowels are a, e, i, o, u and their uppercase version. So you could use this method:

```
private static readonly HashSet<char> Vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };
public static bool IsVowel(char c) => Vowels.Contains(c);
```

and this code to count the vowels:

```
int vowelCount = input.Count(IsVowel);
```

If you don't just want to count them but show them to the user:

```
string vowelsInInput = new String(input.Where(IsVowel).ToArray());
string noVowels = new String(input.Where(c => !IsVowel(c)).ToArray());
```

which also gives you the count(for example `vowelsInInput.Length`).

Comment: The thing is, the user is supposed to enter a line of characters like "djhbviuewh874h3fb" and i'm supposed to split it and organize it then

Comment: yes that's what I meant, but i use visual studio, and there is already a textbox... do i still need to write Console.Readline() if not... what should i write?

Comment: what if i wanna sort the letter in two categories... vocals and normal ones for example

Comment: yes, vowels, well... I'm sorry I guess, but what should I do now?

Comment: I marked it as answered, and tried to post another qs, but I can only post once every 90 min, and I really need this now, so it'd be really nice of you if you could help me!

Comment: @Abdullah: have a look

Answer (score 0):

Get the input and loop through every character within the string

```
string testStr = "abc123";
foreach (char c in testStr)
{
   Console.WriteLine(c.ToString( ));
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to explain more :))

Comment: a string consists of characters so in the above example we are taking a string and then loop through each and every character. you decide what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to count the number of times a letter appears.

```
 char letter = //your letter;
 var charFrequencies = new Dictionary<char, int>();
 if (!charFrequencies.ContainsKey(letter)) {
    charFrequencies.Add(letter, 1);
 }
 else {
    charFrequencies[letter]++;
 }
```